# Saving and restoring resized images using react-native-easy-gestures

Tags: react-native, gesture, sizing

I am creating a react native mobile app where the user can drag small images onto a picture and position them. They can also stretch or shrink the images to create the layout that they want.

I am using react-native-easy-gestures. It works pretty good except I want to be able to save the changes an reload them to the location and size the user set them at.

I cannot figure out how to get the new size and location to save it. And then how to I save it back after recreating the images later. I attempted using useRef and is suggested in a lot of posts but I don't see the style in the object.

If there is a better plugin or another approach to moving, sizing, saving and restoring images I am open to that as well.